# Generate Total Price, multiple products on one page

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to generate the total price on a one page store.

I have different products on the same page laid out like this within a foreach:

```
<input type="hidden" name="price_<?=$product_id?>" value="<?=$product_price?>" />
<input type="text" name="<?=$product_id?>" value="" onchange="calculateTotal();" />
```

So, the first input is hidden and contains the price of the product. The second input contains the quantity, with the name set as the product_id. The only issue is that there can be multiple inputs on one page.

Which would be the best way to do it? Either using Javascript to calculate the price, or an Ajax post and using PHP to do the calculations.

Comment: I'd would do all calculations (business logic) on the server.

Comment: Did you ever figure out your question? Do you accept answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use the new `data` attribute and skip the hidden price field?  Something like this:

```
<input class='quantity' type="number" data-price="1.5"  name="prod1" value="" />
<div class='subtotal'>0.00</div>

<input class='quantity' type="number" data-price="7"  name="prod2" value="" />
<div class='subtotal'>0.00</div>

<div id='total'>0.00</div>
```

with this:

```
$('.quantity').on('change', function(){
    var sub = $(this).val() * $(this).data('price');
    $(this).next('div.subtotal').html(sub).data('sub',sub);
    var tot=0;
    $('.subtotal').each(function(){
            tot+= $(this).data('sub');
        });
    $('div#total').html(tot);
});
```

Comment: This actually what I have been looking for. But in a table format.

Answer (score 0):

Noting that using HTML to store a price variable is *usually* bad etiquette why not keep a running total of all prices? Something like

```
$running_total = $running_total+$product_price;
```

This would output the total of all products that have been cycled through. If I misinterpreted your question I'm sorry.

Storing prices as a an HTML entity to be passed via POST or GET leaves the variable open for manipulation by the end user.

Answer (score 0):

Do it however you want. As long as you perform the calculation at checkout (again?) **on the server**.